# Efficiently search for a single element in a large Pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc

Unless I'm missing something it seems that there are only two ways to "traverse" a `Pandoc` data-structure:

1. Manually pattern-matching on `Block` and `Inline` constructors
2. Via the [`Walkable` type-class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.21/docs/Text-Pandoc-Walk.html) and related utility function

Using the `Walkable` type-class, is there an efficient way to search for the *first* matching element (preferably in a breadth-first manner), and stop the traversal as soon as its found? It seems to me that all functions around the `Walkable` type-class are going to traverse the *entire* data structure no matter what.

If not, I guess the only way is to pattern-match the `Block` and `Inline` constructors and build this on my own.

Comment: `Walkable` gives you `query`, which aggregates it's results with a `Monoid`, can you use the Monoid on  `Option (First a)` to get the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 3):

The other answer points out the useful `query` function. I'd add that there's a [package of pandoc lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-lens). You asked about breadth-first traversal too, so here's both.

```
import Data.Semigroup (First (..))

dfsFirstLink :: Walkable Inline b => b -> Maybe Text
dfsFirstLink = fmap getFirst . query (preview $ _Link . _2 . _1 . to First) 

bfsFirstLink :: Walkable Inline b => b -> Maybe Text
bfsFirstLink = fmap getFirst . getConst . traverseOf (levels query . folded) (Const . preview (_Link . _2 . _1 . to First))

-- Construct a walkable value where dfs != bfs
p :: Pandoc
p = Pandoc mempty [Plain [Note [Plain [Link mempty [] ("a","b")]]],Plain [Link mempty [] ("c","d")]]

>> dfsFirstLink p
Just "a"
>> bfsFirstLink p
Just "c"
```

Though unfortunately some ad-hoc experiments suggest it may not be as lazy as one might hope.

Answer (score 2):

The `Walkable` typeclass contains a function called [`query`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types-1.21/docs/Text-Pandoc-Walk.html#v:query) with the following type signature:

```hs
query :: Monoid c => (a -> c) -> b -> c
```

In `Data.Semigroup`, there's a type called `First`, with a semigroup instance where the accumulating behavior is to return the "leftmost value".

This can be combined with the `Monoid` on `Maybe`, which turns any `Semigroup` into a `Monoid` with `mempty` of `Nothing`, to give the behavior you want.

For example, adapting a function from `Inline -> Maybe String`, to `Pandoc -> Maybe String`, can be done like so:

```hs
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Walk (query)
import Data.Semigroup

findUrl :: Inline -> Maybe String
findUrl (Link _ _ target) = Just $ fst target
findUrl _ = Nothing

findFirstUrl :: Pandoc -> Maybe String
findFirstUrl = (fmap getFirst) . (query findUrl')
  where
    findUrl' :: Inline -> Maybe (First String)
    findUrl' = (fmap First) . findUrl
```

With regards to your concern that this will traverse the entire data structure: Haskell is lazy; it shouldn't traverse any further than it needs to.

As pointed out in the comments, it's also possible to write this by specializing `query` to the List Monoid:

```hs
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Walk (query)
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

findUrl :: Inline -> [String]
findUrl (Link _ _ target) = [fst target]
findUrl _ = []

findFirstUrl :: Pandoc -> Maybe String
findFirstUrl = listToMaybe . (query findUrl)
```

Comment: It's possible that you'll need to change some of the `String`s in my example to `Text` to get it to compile, I tested this on an oldish version of Pandoc, because that was the one that I had installed

Comment: There's also a bunch of "Historical Differences" between the version of `First` in `Data.Semigroup`, and in `Data.Monoid`, I believe the version in `Data.Semigroup` (as described here) is the recommended one

Comment: Two questions: (a) `Maybe a` is a Monoid only if `a` is a `Semigroup`. What if I want to find the first `Pandoc.Block` matching a condition - which is neither a `Semigroup` nor a `Monoid`? (b) Is there anything special with `First` that makes `getFirst` efficient, or is this depending upon the laziness of Haskell?  (docs are too confusing - `Monoid.First`, `Semigroup.First`, and `Option` seem to be in a flux) If this depends primarily upon lazy evaluation, then can `query` be specialised to the list monoid and then we do `Data.List.take 1` on the result? Will it be equally efficient?

Comment: a) First a is a semigroup where `First a <> First b = First a`

Comment: b) there's nothing special about `First` that makes it efficient other than lazy evaluation, I would expect your suggestion about using the list monoid to work, and to be similarly efficient

Comment: I think your suggestion of using the List Monoid is actually easier to understand, I'm going to edit it into the answer.